# Fading AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Okay, I have an ajax script.
It's combined with jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery address 1.3.2.
Basically, I'd like it to fade the divs in and out instead of it just changing as it is now. I want it to look more fluid.

This is the AJAX:

```
jQuery.noConflict()

if( window.location.hash == "" ) {
    window.location.href = "#home";
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {

  jQuery.address.change(onAddressChange);   

  jQuery('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

  jQuery('a[rel=ajax]').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var hash = evt.target.href;
    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#\//, '');
    jQuery.address.value(hash);

    jQuery('#content').hide();
    jQuery('.loading').show();
  });
});

// Handles forms

$( 'form' ).live( 'submit', function() {

        var hash = window.location.hash.replace( '#', '' );
            hash = $.browser.mozilla ? hash : decodeURIComponent( hash );

        if( $( this ).attr( 'action' ) == '' ) $( this ).attr( 'action', hash );

        $( this ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit" />' );

        var data = $( this ).serialize();

        $.post( 'loader.php?page=' + $( this ).attr( 'action' ), data, function( response, status ) {

            if( status == 'error' ) return false;

            $( '#content' ).html( response );

        } );

        return false;

    } );

// End forms

function onAddressChange(evt) {
  var page = evt.value.replace(/[#!\/]/, '');

  jQuery('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
  jQuery('#'+page).addClass('selected');

  var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(page);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "loader.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
      jQuery('.loading').hide();
      jQuery('#content').html(html);
      jQuery('#content').fadeIn('slow');
    }   
  });
}
```

I don't code JS. This was provided to my by a friend.
So if someone could make this fade in/out for me, I'd be more than grateful.

If you need it: www.julake.co.uk/staff/media_123

This is a working example: www.44lizards.com/ajaxcodedrop

Answer (score 0):

CBA to go over that horrible written code, but I'd guess you could just replace ".show()" and ".hide()" with .fadeIn(300) and .fadeOut(300) , which will fade in / out over the time of 0.3 seconds.

So .fadeIn for showing, and .fadeOut for hiding.